# Не работает проект при запуске из visual studio. Unity3D + Newtonsoft.Json + System.ServiceModel.Web

Tags: visual-studio, unity3d

Хочу запустить проект юнити из вижл студии, но неработает.

Unity3D + Newtonsoft.Json + System.ServiceModel.Web

Сам проект:
https://yadi.sk/d/ZRlS2j28r7d9g

Создаю новый Юнити проект.
Добавляю интеграцию с вижл студией в проект.
Asset - import vs tools.
Добавляю в проект dll
\New Unity Project testttt\Assets\plugins\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
\New Unity Project testttt\Assets\plugins\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll

Скрипт не работает.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }


}

public static class X
{
    public static void JSON_SerializeObjToFile(this object obj, string filename)
    {
        var ser_json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
        {
            ser_json.WriteObject(fs, obj);
        }
    }
}
```

> Серьезность Код Описание Проект Файл Строка Состояние подавления
>   Ошибка CS0012 Тип "XmlWriter" определен в сборке, на которую нет
>   ссылки. Следует добавить ссылку на сборку "System.Xml,
>   Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e".
>   New Unity Project testttt.CSharp
>
> Серьезность Код Описание Проект Файл Строка Состояние подавления
>   Ошибка CS0012 Тип "XmlDictionaryWriter" определен в сборке, на которую
>   нет ссылки. Следует добавить ссылку на сборку
>   "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". New Unity Project testttt.CSharp
>
> Серьезность Код Описание Проект Файл Строка Состояние подавления
>   Ошибка CS0012 Тип "XmlObjectSerializer" определен в сборке, на которую
>   нет ссылки. Следует добавить ссылку на сборку
>   "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". New Unity Project testttt.CSharp
>
> Серьезность Код Описание Проект Файл Строка Состояние подавления
>   Ошибка `NewBehaviourScript.JSON_SerializeObjToFile(this object,
>   string)': Extension methods must be defined in a non-generic static
>   class Решение "New Unity Project testttt" ‎ (проектов: 1)
>   Assets/NewBehaviourScript.cs

Вижл студия предлагает добавить две ссылки но при нажатии по ним не добаляются.

Answer (score 2):

Исправлено. добавлением `<FrameworkPathOverride>C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\unity</FrameworkPathOverride>` в .csproj

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
   ...
    <ProjectTypeGuids></ProjectTypeGuids>
    <FrameworkPathOverride>C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\unity</FrameworkPathOverride>
    <TargetFrameworkIdentifier>.NETFramework</TargetFrameworkIdentifier>
```